# Upload multiple images in one record PHP MySql

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I have a working multiple images upload (5 images max.), where I insert them into multiple records. My goal now is to insert them in one record. I am going to explain it with code and screens:

form.html

```
    <form action="imagesupload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
Codice Riferimento: <input type="text" name="codrif" value="<?php echo $codrif; ?>"/><br>


    <div>
        <label for='upload'>Add Attachments:</label>
        <input id='upload' name="upload[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
    </div>

    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></p>

</form>
```

imagesupload.php

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $codrif = $_POST['codrif'];


    if(count($_FILES['upload']['name']) > 0 && count($_FILES['upload']['name']) < 6){
        //Loop through each file
        for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) {
          //Get the temp file path
            $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];

            //Make sure we have a filepath
            if($tmpFilePath != ""){

                //save the filename
                $shortname = $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];

                //save the url and the file
                $filePath = "uploads/" . date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];

                //Upload the file into the temp dir
                if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $filePath)) {

                    $files[] = $shortname;
                    //insert into db 
                    //use $shortname for the filename
                    //use $filePath for the relative url to the file

$servername = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$username = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$sql = "INSERT INTO uploads (codrif, name, imagesname, description)
VALUES ('$codrif', '$name', '$shortname', '$filePath');";


if ($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New records created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();




                }
              }
        }
    }else{
        echo "Error!";    


    }

    //show success message
    echo "<h1>Uploaded:</h1>";    
    if(is_array($files)){
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach($files as $file){
            echo "<li>$file</li>";

        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}
?>
```

and I get this situation in my db:
[image]

Now I'd like to have my 5 images names and path in the same row, something like this:

id   codrif   imagesname1   description1   imagesname2   description2   imagesname3  description3  and so on

Is it possible to do it? Alternative solution?

**EDIT** After Select, I'd like to call single image in my code like $images1, $images2, $images3 and so on

Comment: Read about normalisation and one to many relation ship

Comment: It is possible, however in a relational database you wouldnt do something like that.

Comment: Study normalization.

Comment: You can also use type json to store your image data in key value pair.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my message with more info about my goal, Could you read it please? Thanks again

Comment: You 'would like' something. The question is why? Any good reasons?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yes, because I am building a code to insert a product where I have a big image and multiple images to show

Comment: @James69: That is not a good reason. It is probably a bad reason. As other have said: You should try to normalize your tables. If you don't know what that means then read up on database normalization. Many thousands of people have contributes to this knowledge: It is the best way to do it.

Comment: Yes, I see... Thanks for your advice!